# Is loading a dataframe each time from an SQL database faster than loading it once and save it as a pickle file?

Tags: pandas, postgresql, dataframe, performance, pickle

Would it be quicker to load the dataframes from the Postgres db once and save them as pickle files, rather than loading them directly from the database each time I need to do some processing?

Comment: 1) You are assuming the data is not going to change. 2) Do you even need to use Pandas? You can eliminate a lot of overhead by querying directly via `psycopg2`. You can be even more efficient using [Server side cursors](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors).

Comment: 1) yes the data in postgres is the same 2) I am actually loading some geo data so I am using pandas/geopanda to process the loaded geometries.. You think it should be faster when querying via `psycopg2` and then transforming the tables to dataframes..?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what the end result is supposed to be.

Comment: I just tested loading the data using psycopg2 and it took almost the same time as loading via pandas at least in my case. Next test:  see how long loading data from pickle would take..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing both approaches:

Loading data from a Postgres database and then dumping it as pickle files can be a great way to speed up the processing time, as loading the pickles each time I needed to do some processing was much faster than loading the data each time from the Postgres server directly.

However, one issue that you might encounter is that loading all of the pickle files into memory can take up a lot of RAM, especially if you have a large dataset. One way to mitigate this issue is to load the pickle files incrementally, rather than all at once.